# Django UUIDField Truncates from varchar(36) to char(32)

Tags: python, mysql, django

After upgrading to Django 1.8.3, I needed to change from using `django_extensions.db.fields.UUIDField` to the new `django.db.models.UUIDField`.

The issue is that the old one was defined as `varchar(36)` with hyphens and the new one is `char(32)` without hyphens.
I definitely see the size benefits of not having these hyphens in there.

I gave it a go and, as I feared, the data in the column gets truncated.

When I check the definition of the field, it is initialized with:

```
def __init__(self, verbose_name=None, **kwargs):
    kwargs['max_length'] = 32
    super(UUIDField, self).__init__(verbose_name, **kwargs)
```

This definition blocks any override of the max_length.

Of course I can update every single UUIDFields I have to remove the hyphens but this is quite a long process because my tables are quite big.
For information, this is the kind of query I would have to run:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET uuid_field = REPLACE(uuid_field, '-', '');
```

So my question is, do you have any better idea than running a huge update for every rows of every tables with UUIDFields?

Comment: I think you can override the `UUIDField` and set the max length to 36.

Comment: No I can't because of the definition of the UUIDField:`kwargs['max_length'] = 32`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh well, it's way too painful to update every UUID fields in the database, I'm reimplementing something similar to the old `django_extensions.db.fields.UUIDField`.

Django's first aim is Postgres which has its own UUID field type (without hyphens) but MySQL doesn't.

Django's new UUIDField works well if you are creating a new field but it's a pain if you already have data.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this same issue. Ended up just taking the easy route and defining my own model field.

```
from django.db import models


class UUIDField(models.UUIDField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['max_length'] = 36
        super(models.UUIDField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```